# REST API call using Swift to recreate App Store

Tags: ios, swift, api

So I have two models, one called AppCategory and App. I've created a function within the AppCategory class that makes an API call that brings me back all categories successfully and within those categories there is an array of dictionaries of apps which I get back in form of dictionaries but i'm not sure on how to set it as an App object.

Here is my AppCategory class:

```
import UIKit

class AppCategory {

var name: String?
var apps = [App]()
var type: String?

  init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
      name = dictionary["name"] as? String
      apps = dictionary["apps"] as! [App]
      type = dictionary["type"] as? String
  }

  static func fetchFeaturedApps(completion: @escaping ([AppCategory]) -> Void) {
      guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured") else { return }

      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
          if error != nil {
              print(error!.localizedDescription)
              return
          }

          guard let data = data else { return }

          do {
              let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

              var appCategories = [AppCategory]()

              for dict in json["categories"] as! [[String: Any]] {
                  let appCategory = AppCategory(dictionary: dict)
                  appCategories.append(appCategory)

                  if dict.index(forKey: "apps") != nil {

                  }
              }
              print(appCategories)
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  completion(appCategories)
              }

          } catch {
              print("Error in JSON Serialization")
          }
      }.resume()
  }
}
```

Here is the App model class:

```
import Foundation

class App {

var id: Int?
var name: String?
var category: String?
var price: Double?
var imageName: String?

  init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
      id = dictionary["Id"] as? Int
      name = dictionary["Name"] as? String
      category = dictionary["Category"] as? String
      price = dictionary["Price"] as? Double
      imageName = dictionary["ImageName"] as? String
  }
}
```

I've done research and I could make these classes of type NSObject and use the setValue(forKey:) but I don't really want to do that. I've gotten as far as what's highlighted in the AppCategory class by saying if dict.index(forKey: "apps") != nil... Don't know if i'm on the right track but maybe someone can help me with this.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing the Decodable protocol?

Comment: Yes, which worked just fine and so did the NSObject setValue method, but I’m trying to figure out how to do so w/ out using either. Even though Decodable is probably the way I’ll go once I figure this out.